# How can you simply resue HTML code?

Tags: html

A similar question has been posted before but the answeres were not exactly what I wanted. I apologize if the question is illy phrase.

My problem is very straightforward. I have some HTML that I need to use multiple times on one page. For instance:

```
        <tr>
            <th>First Element</th>
            <th>Second Element</th>
            <th>Third Element</th>
            <th>Fourth Element</th>
            <th>Fifth Element</th>
        </tr>
```

As it is now done, people just copy paste this around a couple of times. Is there any simple way in which the code can be reused?

Comment: Yes,
You can use any kind of template engine like Smarty or Razor or blade etc to create dynamic code based on your data.

Comment: You can use Web Components. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Answer (score 0):

you could use Javascript to create it with a for-loop something like this :

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
 template = "<tr>
        <th>First Element</th>
        <th>Second Element</th>
        <th>Third Element</th>
        <th>Fourth Element</th>
        <th>Fifth Element</th>
    </tr>"
 document.getElementById("trId").innerHTML += template;
}
```

You could then add some logic to manipulate each element before adding it.
That would be one solution, but you should look into Angular where you could make this a Component and just use this component with input parameters.
You can start right here https://angular.io/tutorial

Cheers